# Assigning a CRS to RaterBrick in R

Tags: r, raster, coordinate-systems, proj

I tried converting this `df (c.data)` to a RasterBrick and set the `crs` to `EPSG:3035`; Lambert Equal Area Europe with the code. The code creates the raster, but it does not set the CRS

```
c.data
# A tibble: 361,478 x 6
         x       y   pop women mean_age hh_size
     <int>   <int> <int> <int>    <int>   <int>
 1 4334500 2684500    NA    NA       NA      NA
 2 4335500 2684500    NA    NA       NA      NA
 3 4336500 2684500    NA    NA       NA      NA
 4 4337500 2684500    NA    NA       NA      NA
 5 4338500 2684500    NA    NA       NA      NA
 6 4339500 2684500    NA    NA       NA      NA
 7 4334500 2685500    NA    NA       NA      NA
 8 4335500 2685500    NA    NA       NA      NA
 9 4336500 2685500    NA    NA       NA      NA
10 4337500 2685500    NA    NA       NA      NA
# ... with 361,468 more rows
```

```
c.data_ras <- rasterFromXYZ(c.data, crs = st_crs(3035)$proj4string)
```

```
    c.data_ras
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 868, 642, 557256, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
extent     : 4031000, 4673000, 2684000, 3552000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : pop, women, mean_age, hh_size 
min values :   1,     1,        1,       1 
max values :   6,     5,        5,       5
```

Instead, I get this warning

Warning message:

```
In .newCRS(value) :
+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs is not a valid PROJ.4 CRS string
```

Please, how do I go about this?

Thanks

Thanks @lime and @sequoia I tried both suggestions, but I still get the same errors

```
c.data_ras <- rasterFromXYZ(c.data, crs = st_crs("+init=epsg:3035")$proj4string)

Warning message:
    In .newCRS(value) :
      +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs is not a valid PROJ.4 CRS string
```

and

```
c.data_ras <- rasterFromXYZ(c.data, crs = st_crs("EPSG:3035")$proj4string)
Warning message:
In .newCRS(value) :
  +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs is not a valid PROJ.4 CRS string
```

Comment: replace `st_crs(3035)` with `st_crs("EPSG:3035")`

Comment: ... or with `, crs = "+init=epsg:3035"`. I tried with sample data from the `rasterFromXYZ`help page, it worked

Comment: oops, I meant to say `st_crs("ESRI:3035")` this should work and its much faster, I had an issue with this a while back and this fixed it.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these worked for me.

Comment: try `crs( c.data_ras) <- "+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs"`